# Changing Shapefiles structure for tmap in R

Tags: r, google-maps, shapefile, tmap, rgeo-shapefile

I would like to know if changing shapefile specifications is possible.

I'm trying to create a map witht the `tmap` package in R.

If I look for the shapefiles in national websites. I can't find the one the Ministry of Public Health created. Since I have the original shapefile 2010 territorial division, how can I create a new map, in order to use it in `tmap` with the new provinces in diferent regions.

Forgive the spanish.

The map I want to create:
[image]

Changes and explanation:
[image]

This is the link for the zipped shapefile:
https://geoportal.iderd.gob.do/layers/geonode:RD_RUP/metadata_detail

Comment: One way would be to open the shape file in QGis and edit the attribute table.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: the provinces did not change border, but belong to different regions, and you would like to update the provinces to their newest region? As @RomanLuštrik suggested, you can edit the attribute table in QGIS, but you can also do that directly in R: the shapefile is a `data.frame`, and the columns can be modified directly using `dplyr` for example (`mutate(region = case_when(province == 1 ~ regionA, ...))`, for example).

Comment: Not sure if I follow. Is it about creating a choropleth map, but the region classification of the data source does not match the updated Shapefile? Or is it just about updating `tmap` code for the new Shapefile? For the latter, it would help if you'd show your code and describe what issues you were running into.